# Network PCs Lost internet, Server Doesnt

Tags: networking, internet, windows-server, small-business-server

I currently have a small server (running Windows Small Business Server 2011 Essentials) and 3 pcs set up in a network. I moved the server this morning, unpacked a new printer and plugged it into the router to set up.All 3 pcs are plugged into the router, but have no internet connection but the server does. I can ping from any machine to any machine, just no internet on PCs. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What os is on the server?

Comment: sbs 2011 essentials

Comment: Do the PC's and SRV have their IP's statically assigned? I'd think you need to power cycle the router which should resolve the issue...

Comment: look at the PCS and and make sure they can ping their default GW, also look and make sure their subnet mask is correct and they have a DNS server configured.

Comment: Power Cycle worked! Thanks all for the help, is there a reason for this or a way to prevent it?

Comment: s*IT happens and superuser is nothing short of proof of this fact in real-time! Technology doesn't always work as advertised...and sometimes it stops working just for no good reason at all. Welcome to IT  :)